# can't declare localStorage with onClick

Tags: javascript

It can't handle the code below, I don't know why:

```
<input type="button" value="Map" onclick="open_win(); localStorage.setItem("mapSelect", "map1");">
```

I wish to declare the localStorage variable when I press that particular button. Can I do this in another way?

Comment: look at the syntax highlight and everything will be clear

Comment: If you found a good answer to your question, select it in order to close the topic and other people coming here can find easily the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, you have double-quotes into an html attribute surrounded by double quotes too.

use HTML characters :

```
<input type="button" value="Map" onclick="open_win(); localStorage.setItem(&quot;mapSelect&quot;, &quot;map1&quot;);">
```

Or use single-quotes:

```
<input type="button" value="Map" onclick="open_win(); localStorage.setItem('mapSelect', 'map1');">
```

But the best way to do it is to have the less code possible in the `onclick` attribute. You can write a function and call only it in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: backslash does not escape characters in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Any editor with colour coding clearly reveals the issue. Use single-quotes, or escape the inner quotes:

```
onclick="open_win(); localStorage.setItem(&quot;mapSelect&quot;,&quot;map1&quot;);"
```

Comment: thanks, solved it with open_win(mapVar), mapVar is a string var.